# Automatic redirection in plone?

Tags: plone

I have renamed an object id and thought I'd have to write a redirection in my vhost, but after trying to access my object with the old url (the one before the object id was renamed), I saw that plone redirect me to the new object's url.

Can someone tell me which products or functionality enabled this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is provided by plone.app.redirector (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.redirector/), which is part of the Plone core distribution.